# Prove that orthogonal projections are linear

Tags: linear-algebra

In chapter 8 of Hoffman and Kunze, an orthogonal projection is defined as follows. Let V be a finite dim inner product space over field K, W a subspace of V. E is an orthogonal projection from V to W if $\forall x \in V,  \| x - Ex \| \le \| x - w \| \forall w \in W$, that is, Ex is the best approximation of x in W. Here, $\|x\| = (x | x)$, where (.|.) is the inner product on V.

They then prove that E is linear with the following argument. If $x,y \in V$, and $k \in K$ then $x - Ex, y - Ey \in W^\perp$. Hence, k(x - Ex) + (y - Ey) = (kx + y) - (kEx + Ey) is in $W^\perp$. I follow up until this point. Then, however, they just assume this must mean E(kx + y) = kEx + Ey, which I don't follow.

Comment: if $a \in W$ and $b \in W^\perp$ then $E(a+b) = a$. clearly $E((a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)) = a_1+a_2 = E(a_1+b_1)+E(a_2+b_2)$, while $E(cx) = cx$ for every $c \in K$,  hence it is linear

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. E(kx + y) = E( (kEx + Ey) + (k(x - Ex) + (y - Ey)) ) = kEx + Ey.  Why is the statement 'if a∈W  and b∈W⊥, then E(a+b)=a ' true? I see why intuitively, but can you show it from the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see it now. As user1952009 said, if $a\in W$ and $b\in W^\perp$ then  E(a+b)=a. This is implied by Theorem 4 on page 284, which requires some work. But, with that,

it follows that E(kx + y) = E( (kEx + Ey) + (k(x - Ex) + (y - Ey)) ) = kEx + Ey